# Read .docx paragraphs with formatting

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, docx

I am using ASP.NET to let the user upload a .docx file and then the application retrieve information from that file and save in database.

I managed to read the text in tables, but i can not read the formatting and styles of that text.

I want to read the paragraph with formatting so that the user can see his text formatting when appear in editors like CKEditor.

Comment: I don't know how you got your text out of the docx, but you could have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914677/creating-rtf-doc-docx-with-ios or eventually this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899883/how-can-i-use-docx-js-to-generate-a-word-document-in-javascript/16941279#16941279

Comment: What exactly have you tried to do ? Do you use any libraries ?